# Using jQuery data for processing RESTfull requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I am trying to filter somehow the request response based on the returned status code. I found how I can get the status code using the "complete" statement, but I do not know how to get the handler to the data. In the example I want to include the error statement and the success statement in the complete handler, and being able there to process the data.

```
$.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      url:  url,
      cache: false,
      type: 'GET',
      async: true,
      error: function(){
            //process error
        
       },
      success: function(data){
        //process data
      },
      complete: function(transport) {

        switch(transport.status){
            case 200:
                //process data
                break;
            case 202:
                //process data
            
                break;
            case 304:
                //do not process data
            
                break;
            default:
                //default processing
                break;
        }
      }
                  
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You actual response is `transport`

So you can use `transport.responseText` to get the string response (before it's parsed, that happens in `success`)

Comment: Thanks Horia. The problem is that i receive a pretty big json response. and what i get from the responseText is a string. which would be the best way to process it? I sometimes become a very larege response string.  In the success handler i get directly the json object in the data variable.